# Show that no nonconstant analytic polynomials can take imaginary values only

Tags: complex-analysis

Note: as a non-native English speaker, my main confusion of this problem is to understand what does it mean by 'taking imaginary values only'.

On the one hand, it can be viewed as P(x,y) takes only imaginary input, in which case, P(x,y) equals P(0,y) and $P_{x} = 0$  immediately. It follows that $P_{y} = 0$ by Cauchy-Riemann condition and we conclude immediately the polynomial is a constant.

On the other hand, it can be viewed as P(x,y) only has imaginary output, in which case, P(x,y) = iv(x,y), given that $u_{x}= 0$ and $u_{y}=0$ the function **v** becomes a constant immediately, and the result follows.

Comment: @Kavi.  Has the title changed?  The statement "no non-constant analytic polynomials can take imaginary values only" seems to me to be true if interpreted according to the second option in the question (the first option has doubtful use).  Every polynomial in a complex variable $z$ muts also be analytic, so the OP proof would seem to work.